Do wind turbines spin at constant speed? If so, how?
All electrical power fed into the electric grid needs to be an AC power source at 60 Hz (in the U.S.) to within a very tight tolerance.
My understanding is that steam turbines are kept rotating at a fixed angular speed of 60 Hz (or an integer fraction of that frequency for a multi-pole generator) via a steam turbine governor system that dynamically adapts the torque that the steam exerts on the turbine blades. (Essentially, it does so by keeping the torque $\tau$ equal to the dynamically varying external electrical load $P$ divided by the target angular speed $\omega$, thereby keeping the ratio $\omega = P / \tau$ constant.)
I believe (but am not positive) that wind turbines also spin at a constant angular speed, but typically one that is much smaller than 60 Hz, and there is usually a set of gears with a fixed effective gear ratio that increases the rotational speed that is delivered to the generator itself up to the desired 60 Hz.
But for a wind turbine, the wind speed (which determines the torque exerted on the blades) varies outside of the operator's control. How is the turbine's angular speed kept constant?
I assume that when the wind is below some critical speed, the turbine is allowed to spin freely (or is probably clamped stationary to reduce wear on the rotation mechanism). And then whenever the wind picks up to the critical speed required to spin the blades at the target frequency, the turbine is allowed to spin up to the target speed, and then simultaneously (a) it is brought onto the electrical grid and (b) some governor mechanism keeps its rotational frequency constant until the wind dies down again. Is this picture roughly correct?
Or if I'm incorrect and the blades' rotational speed varies in proportion to the torque exerted by the wind, then how is the generator always kept at the 60 Hz target frequency?

Please migrate this to engineering to preserve the answer.

While a large turbine will try to hold rotation constant by driving the pitch of the blades, this is not able to completely compensate for gusts and other rapid changes in speed.   If such a system were directly attached to grid frequency with a traditional generator, there would be a lot of stress on components any time the shaft speed didn't exactly line up with the target speed for the grid.
Smaller turbines can use AC->DC->AC conversion with an inverter.   But the more popular choice these days for large turbines seems to be doubly fed induction generators.
This is a generator which has a field inside that is driven electronically by a control unit.   The unit can set the rotational speed of the driven field such that the sum of the input shaft rotation and the electronically rotating field is equal to the desired output frequency.
This allows for variation in the input speed without a full DC->AC inverter.

I've also heard of them using a hydraulic system (somewhat like a CVT on a car) to match the variable turbine speed to the fixed grid speed. I don't know whether this is current or obsolescent.

@nigel222 Obsolete; doubly fed generators have no moving parts that wear out and no oil that has to be changed. Gearboxes that can handle megawatts of power are expensive and big.
